# Hosting a WCF service as a WindowsService?

Tags: wpf, wcf, windows-services, endpoint-address

Can anyone tell me the method to host a WCF service Library as a windows service?
I have tried to follow various links but always get some or the other error.
Either the service starts and stops immediately or the client is unable to access the service hosted on windows..I am using simple WPF app as a client.

Also can anyone tell me difference between the end point address and the base address and what should be there set to while hosting WCF as Windows Service

App.config for WCF service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mysqlconnection" connectionString="Initial catalog=calculator; data source=10.2.108.251; User Id=sa; Password=abc@123"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Calculator1.CalculatorService1" behaviorConfiguration="Calculator1.BasicCalculator">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Calculator1.ICalculator1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Calculator1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Calculator1.BasicCalculator">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

app.config that i generated using SvcUtil.exe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:9001/CalculatorService1"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator1"
                contract="ICalculator1" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Windows sErvices file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace WindowsSErviceCalculator1
{
    public partial class CalculatorWindowsService1 : ServiceBase
    {
        ServiceHost m_svcHost = null;
        public CalculatorWindowsService1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (m_svcHost != null)
            {
                m_svcHost.Close();
            }
            string strAdrHTTP = "http://localhost:9001/CalculatorService1";
            Uri[] adrbase = { new Uri(strAdrHTTP) };
            m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Calculator1.CalculatorService1), adrbase);

            ServiceMetadataBehavior mBehave = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            m_svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(mBehave);

            BasicHttpBinding httpb = new BasicHttpBinding();
            m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Calculator1.ICalculator1), httpb, strAdrHTTP);
            m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

            m_svcHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (m_svcHost != null)
            {
                m_svcHost.Close();
                m_svcHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `svcutil.exe`. Right-click the "References" section in Visual Studio and select `Add Service reference`. The service needs to be started for this.

Comment: i used to do it with "Add service reference" previously..but used to get the same error..so this time i went with svcutil.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you can host the service as a console application for example, you take the service configuration from that applications `app.config` file and copy it to the service's `app.config` file.

There's no difference whatsoever between hosting a WCF service from an application or a service.

That being said, a service will not keep running unless you tell it to do something. Technically speaking: There must be some loop (ideally a timer or a thread) that keeps the service alive. If you don't have that, the service will start and stop right away.

---

Aha! From the edit of your question one thing becomes obvious: You're overwriting the configuration from the `app.config` with stuff done in code. You need to decide for one way: Either to everything through the `app.config` file (which I recommend)  or do everything in code.

Comment: even if i do that and i am able to get the service up and running whenever i try to execute my WPF app it stops with the error that it is unable to access that particular service. what could be the error in such a case? and is it possible that this error is because of some error in the config file for the windows service?

Comment: I followed this link..http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38160/WCF-Service-Library-with-Windows-Service-Hosting

Comment: Well, the config file for the windows service contains the service configuration for the WCF service, so yes, it is well possible that you have a problem there. Can you host the WCF service from another application, like a console application? Do you create the service host properly in your service's code (in OnStart)? I doubt this has anything to do with the service, but as you've not posted any code or configuration information, I can not tell.

Comment: App.Config for WCF service

Comment: Don't post it as a comment! Edit your question!

Comment: followed this link for this particular project..http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/653493/WCF-Hosting-with-Windows-Service

Comment: See my edit. Short: Remove the stuff from your code and do everything through the config. (And after that update the service reference in the client).

Comment: can you explain me how am  i overwriting the stuff? are you talking about the configuration file of the WCF service?